# Is it possible to send 2 parameters to a new page in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a small paginated app in c#/wpf/xaml.  I am trying to send some variable data from page 1 to page 2 but on some occasions i need to send more than one object/type/piece of data.
In some circumstances i am sending an entire dictionary across and in others i need to send the entire dictionary AND a Textbox.Text entry across (which the user has entered so i cant use a constant)

Is there an easy way to do this?
I am currently ending across the dictionary simply by using:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), MyCustomDictionary));
```

And i am receiving it on page 2 using

```
//MyDictionary defined globally for this page

MyDictionary= (Dictionary<string, MyCustomType>)e.Parameter;
```

The sending and receiving of this works fine, but i need to send a Textbox.Text along with it too...how can i do this?

Comment: Fastest way I can think of: Create a new class with two properties: dictionary and text and pass this to your navigate.

Comment: Thanks Ben - that does sound like the simplest way of doing it.  Thanks